# number of stacks in process userspace when threads are used

Tags: process, pthreads, stack

There is a separate stack created for each pthread in process userspace when pthread_create() is used

Does it mean that if I call pthread_create() inside main() N times, then the number of actual threads within the process and correspondingly the number of stacks within userspace will be N + 1 ?

I'm just confused by this pic

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/images/thread.gif

because it does not show any stack for main()

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main() is a thread too.  If it was not, it would have no execution and so could not do anything:)

So, yes.  If you create N threads in main(), you end up with N+1 threads and, so, N+1 stacks.

Comment: thanks for your reply, one more question, virtual memory creates an illusion that the process may use the whole 0-(2^32-1) virtual address space, assuming that we have 32-bit system; does it mean that each thread within a single process, has an illusion of possessing 0-(2^32-1) virtual address space?

Comment: i guess, if every process has an illusion of using the whole virtual address space, and has more than one thread running within itself, then every thread also has an illusion of possessing the whole virtual address space EXCEPT stack areas of OTHER threads within the same process?